# For loop with if statements isn't working as expected in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, if-statement

It only prints the "else" statement for everything but I know for a fact the files exist that it's looking for.  I've tried adapting some of the other answers but I thought this should definitely work.

**Does anyone know what's wrong with my syntax?**

```
# Contents of script
for ID_SAMPLE in $(cut -f1 metadata.tsv | tail -n +2);
    do if [ -f ./output/${ID_SAMPLE} ]; then
        echo Skipping ${ID_SAMPLE};
    else
        echo Processing ${ID_SAMPLE};
    fi
done
```

**Additional information**

```
# Output directory
(base) -bash-4.1$ ls -lhS output/
total 170K
drwxr-xr-x 8 jespinoz tigr 185 Jan  3 16:16 ERR1701760
drwxr-xr-x 8 jespinoz tigr 185 Jan 17 18:03 ERR315863
drwxr-xr-x 8 jespinoz tigr 185 Jan 16 23:23 ERR599042
drwxr-xr-x 8 jespinoz tigr 185 Jan 17 00:10 ERR599072
drwxr-xr-x 8 jespinoz tigr 185 Jan 16 13:00 ERR599078

# Example of inputs
(base) -bash-4.1$ cut -f1 metadata.tsv | tail -n +2 | head -n 10
ERR1701760
ERR599078
ERR599079
ERR599070
ERR599071
ERR599072
ERR599073
ERR599074
ERR599075
ERR599076

# Output of script
(base) -bash-4.1$ bash test.sh | head -n 10
Processing ERR1701760
Processing ERR599078
Processing ERR599079
Processing ERR599070
Processing ERR599071
Processing ERR599072
Processing ERR599073
Processing ERR599074
Processing ERR599075
Processing ERR599076


# Checking a directory
(base) -bash-4.1$ ls -l ./output/ERR1701760
total 294
drwxr-xr-x  2 jespinoz tigr   386 Jan 15 21:00 checkpoints
drwxr-xr-x  2 jespinoz tigr     0 Jan 10 01:36 tmp
```

Comment: Is `ID_SAMPLE` correct?

Comment: Yea, apologies for leaving out that info.  I've updated my question with more info

Comment: What happens if you add a `!` before the `-f`? Is the result the same?

Comment: What happens if you add a `;` after the `do`?

Comment: @O.rka, Could you please do check if there is NO space in output of your command `cut -f1 metadata.tsv | tail -n +2 | head -n 10` once? Do like `cut -f1 metadata.tsv | tail -n +2 | head -n 10 | cat -e` and let us know here.

Comment: When I add `!` before `-f` all of them come back as "Skipping".  If I add a `;` after the `do` then I get a syntax error :( @dan1st

Comment: What do you see if you do `ls -l ./output/ERR1701760`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 it doesn't look like there are any spaces I just checked.  That's a good idea to check for that tho.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Since he didn't quote `$ID_SAMPLE` the spaces would be removed anyway. I had the same thought about CRLF, but CR will be removed from unquoted variables.

Comment: @Barmar I've added it in the post.  It shows the subdirectories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-f` is for checking whether the name is a file, but all your names are directories. Use `-d` to check that.

```
if [ -d "./output/$ID_SAMPLE" ]
then
```

If you want to check whether the name exists with any type, use `-e`.

Comment: Wow, great find.  I didn't know there was a distinction.